# How to save darkMode in local storage in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage, use-effect, darkmode

I want to save in **local storage** what theme the user has chosen - light or dark, so that when the page refreshes the theme is still current with the user's choice. I tried using the useEffect hook for this, but I am probably doing something wrong.
I have included the code below:

```
function App() {
// Theme
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState('light');
    const checkTheme = () => theme === 'light' ? setTheme('dark') : setTheme('light') ;

// Amount of Portions
const [amountOfPortions , setAmountOfPortions] = useState(1);

const updateAmountOfPortions = (dataFromChild) => {
    setAmountOfPortions(dataFromChild);
};

return (
    <div className={`app wrapper app__bgc--${theme}`}>
        <Switch onChange={checkTheme} color="primary"/>
        <MainCard update={updateAmountOfPortions}/>
        <Recipe value={amountOfPortions}/>
    </div>
    
)};
```

Comment: What did you tried with useEffect ?

Comment: post your code cotaining the useEffect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are just setting state which will be lost once the component refreshes

You need to write a function using the localStorage api. something like:

```
const setThemeInStorage = (theme) => {
   localStorage.setItem('theme', theme)
}
```

then call it like

```
setThemeInStorage('light')
```

and retrieve it like so:

```
const getThemeInStorage = () => {
   localStorage.getItem('theme') // returns 'light' in this case
}
```

if you want to run this code instantly do

`const theme = getThemeInStorage()`
then `theme` is the value of localStorage

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
function persistItem(key: string, value: string) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, value)
    return value
}

function usePersistState(key: string, initialValue?: string) {
    const [state, setState] = useState(
        () => localStorage.getItem(key) || persistItem(key, initialValue)
    )
    const setStateAndPersist = useCallback(
        (newState: string) => {
            setState(newState)
            return persistItem(key, newState)
        },
        [key, setState]
    )
    return [state, setStateAndPersist]
}
```

In your component, simply `const [theme, setTheme] = usePersistState("theme", "light")`. This will default to "light" if nothing was found in `localStorage`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is using a custom hook like [useLocalStorage](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/). If you don't want to use the hook, they still have the code that implements the `localStorage` writing/reading part with comments explaining how they do it so that you can do it in a different way (though I can't think why you would).